# Circular Image Becoming a Diamond Not Circle - Swift 3

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, constraints, swift3

I have been trying to create a circular image but for some reason it has been outputting as a diamond. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    displayEmailFullNameImage()

    self.editProfilePictureImage.layer.cornerRadius = editProfilePictureImage.frame.size.width / 2
    self.editProfilePictureImage.clipsToBounds = true
    self.editProfilePictureImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

}
```

My Constraints on the photo:

[image]

I have tried the following solution:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.width / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

BUT this does not work either.

This is how the image looks:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem it is probably caused by some constraints you have added to your imageView

Comment: Try adding only 4 constraints, 1 for fixed width, 1 for fixed height, 1 for leading space and 1 for top space

Comment: never mind thanks that worked

Comment: can u post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem it is probably caused by some constraints you have added to your imageView. Try adding only 4 constraints, 1 for fixed width, 1 for fixed height, 1 for leading space and 1 for top space as you can see at the screenshot below:

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is too early in the layout process. You can do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = min(profilePic.frame.width, profilePic.frame.height) / 2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use a designable view, and let the view take care of it:

```
@IBDesignable class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
    }
}
```

And by making it designable, you can see it rendered with rounded corners right in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but because I had copied and pasted the cell from another view, the cell class was giving it instructions meant for another cell.